# Don't refocus the question editor when clicking the preview

Tags: feature-request, editor, markdown-preview

When I click the preview below the editor of a new question or answer, the editor gets refocused. (This issue does not apply when editing a question or answer.) Meaning I can't select text to copy. This is an annoying problem, especially on Stack Overflow, where I'm copying my code to make a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

The only solution at the moment is to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> combination before the `mouseup`.

Comment: I am 99.9% sure this is a dupe; it only happens when posting a new post, at the moment, when editing an existing one you can click in the preview just fine.

Comment: Out of time to find one now though..

Comment: @MartijnPieters The [dupe was deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81712/unselectable-text-in-post-body-preview), for some reason. People making me think I'm crazy searching for something that I can't possibly find on the site *grumbles*

Comment: @Oded: Uhm, why did you delete that bug report? Should such bugs be reported elsewhere?

Comment: ~9 years later, problem still there. Or it's feature, like scroll-to-top button?